# pandas.to_csv to write arcpy.getrasterproperties returns

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pandas

I'm stumped on how I can use pandas.to_csv for this application. I'm trying to first write a CSV then append the CSV within the for loop so that every iteration appends a new row.

```
import arcpy, numpy, pandas
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley5\SDepth2"
headers = ["ROWCOUNT", "COLUMNCOUNT", "MAX", "MIN"]
pandas.to_csv(r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley5\output_tabs\CalcPropOut.csv", header = headers, mode = "w")

for file in arcpy.ListRasters():
    ROWCOUNT = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(file,"ROWCOUNT")
    COLUMNCOUNT = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(file,"COLUMNCOUNT")
    MAX = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(file,"MAXIMUM")
    MIN = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(file,"MINIMUM")
    pandas.to_csv(r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley5\output_tabs\CalcPropOut.csv", sep=",", na_rep='-9999', columns=headers, mode="a")
```

Comment: It looks like you just want to pull raster stats for every raster in a directory and put that information into a CSV file? Is using pandas a requirement? Theres some built in CSV writers which might be a bit easier. (But yes, pandas is great)

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions. I thought I'd try pandas b/c it seems to need minimal code. You are correct about the general workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be cleaned up a touch, but it works. If I had pandas installed I would have tried to give it a go, but I didnt....

```
import arcpy
import csv

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Data\Raster\Dems"

headers = ["RNAME", "ROWCOUNT", "COLUMNCOUNT", "MAX", "MIN"]

outputCSV = r"D:\Data\Raster\Dems\stats.csv"
wfile  = open(outputCSV, 'wb')
csvwriter = csv.writer(wfile)

csvwriter.writerow(headers)

for f in arcpy.ListRasters():

    print("Processing : {0}".format(f))

    try:
        ROWCOUNT = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(f,"ROWCOUNT")
        COLUMNCOUNT = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(f,"COLUMNCOUNT")
        MAX = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(f,"MAXIMUM")
        MIN = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(f,"MINIMUM")
    except:
        print("had a problem getting stats for   {0} ".format(f))

    csvwriter.writerow([f, ROWCOUNT, COLUMNCOUNT, MAX, MIN])
```

Comment: Wow great :) I'm still a ways from making code with this much detail.